# Image upload issue: Angularjs and Laravel API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, http-headers, laravel-5.3

I am trying to upload image on my server but my api didn't get the file and says "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null". I don't know where is the problem . here is my code. I am not getting how to validate it. please help me.

**Request headers**

```
Accept:/
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1164
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Host:{url}:8081
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/contacts
UID:7798616828
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.23.2883.75 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Request payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ID"

203
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkNumber"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkSize"

1048576
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowCurrentChunkSize"

812402
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalSize"

812402
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowIdentifier"

812402-C360_2017-01-05-13-21-41-180jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowFilename"

C360_2017-01-05-13-21-41-180.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowRelativePath"

C360_2017-01-05-13-21-41-180.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalChunks"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi--
```

**html**

```
           <div id="contact-image-uploader"
              flow-init="vm.ngFlowOptions"
              flow-name="vm.ngFlow.flow"
              flow-files-submitted="vm.upload($file)"
              flow-file-added="vm.fileAdded($file)"
              flow-file-success="vm.fileSuccess($file, $message)"
              flow-complete="vm.uploadComplete()"
              flow-drop
              flow-drag-enter="vm.dropping=true"
              flow-drag-leave="vm.dropping=false"
              ng-class="{'dropping':vm.dropping}">

              <md-button aria-label="Add file" translate flow-btn>
              <img ng-src="{{vm.contact.image}}" class="md-avatar avatar    contact-avatar huge"alt="{{vm.contact.name}}"/>
                        </md-button>
      </div>
```

**Angular code**

```
function upload(image)
        {
          vm.ngFlow.flow.opts.headers = {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'UID'    : '7798616828'
            };
            vm.ngFlow.flow.opts.query = {'ID':'203'};
            vm.ngFlow.flow.opts.testMethod = 'post';
            vm.ngFlow.flow.opts.uploadMethod = 'post';
            vm.ngFlow.flow.opts.target = 'http://{url}/contact/image/upload';

            vm.ngFlow.flow.upload();
        }
```

**Laravel API**

```
public function upload_image(Request $request){

        $photo = $request->file('file');
        $imagename = time().'.'.$photo->getClientOriginalExtension(); 

        $destinationPath_thumb = storage_path('images/contact/thumbnail_images');
        $thumb_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(100, 100);
        $thumb_img->save($destinationPath_thumb.'/'.$imagename,80);

        $destinationPath_medium = storage_path('images/contact/medium_images');
        $medium_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(500, 500);
        $medium_img->save($destinationPath_medium.'/'.$imagename,80);

        $destinationPath_original = storage_path('images/contact/original_images');
        $photo->move($destinationPath_original, $imagename);

        $user = \App\User::select(['inst_id'])->where('mobile','=',$request->header('UID'))->first();

        $update_img = \App\Contact::where([['id','=',$request->ID],['inst_id','=',$user->inst_id]])->update(['image'=>$imagename]);

        if($update_img)
          $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>0,  'error_msg'=>'', 'message'=>'Profile updated']);
        else
          $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1,  'error_msg'=>'some went wrong', 'message'=>'Please try again']);

    return  $response;
  }
```

Comment: This field looks empty: `------WebKitFormBoundaryQV7RNhEPsxqsIhSi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

`

Comment: I also have same doubt. but why it is going empty?. flow.upload () should take care of that.

Comment: I'm not seeing any `<input type="file" flow-btn />` in your upload code....

Comment: you can see my html code. it is there on <md-button>.